# How to simplify this block diagram to get the given transfer function?

Tags: control, transfer-function

[image]

Given this block diagram, I'm trying to derive the transfer function. I've tried moving the 2 branch to either side of the then getting something like this

[image]

But I'm not sure how to simplify it from there. Any guidance would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let \$g_1 = {10 \over s+1}, g_2 = {1 \over s}\$, and let \$w\$ be the output of the \$g_1\$ block.

You get \$w = g_1 (u - 2 w -g_2 w)\$, which gives
\$w = {g_1 \over1 + 2 g_1 + g_1 g_2} u\$, and so
\$y = {g_2 g_1 \over1 + 2 g_1 + g_1 g_2} u\$, or
\$y = {1  \over 1+{2 \over g_2}+{1 \over g_1 g_2}} u\$ if you would prefer.

Substituting in the values for \$g_1, g_2\$ gives the transfer function you wanted.

Comment: MaxJax is definitely supported here. It's been kind of flaky the last few days.

Comment: @MattYoung: How do I used it? I tried a quick search but found nothing. On some sites I just do $...$ to enclose the formula.

Comment: @copper http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @JYelton: I am mostly a MSE user, so I am very familiar with that. But it does not work when I write equations above.

Comment: @copper It must differ on other sites... Here to use it *inline* `\$` to escape, and to use it on a line of its own, use `$$`.

Comment: @JYelton: Excellent, thanks! On MSE there is no need to escape the $ on inline, so I didn't try anything else. Much appreciated.

Comment: @copper No problem. I haven't used it on other sites, though I noticed it didn't seem to work at all on DIY; perhaps I need to use the MSE convention.

Comment: Very good explanation

Comment: I actually found it was easier for me to solve graphically than mathematically. From the second picture I simplified the right parallel branches to `H=2s+1`, with `G=10/(s2+s)` then substituted those into the negative feedback equation `TF=G/(1+GH)` and solved it from there. Thanks for your guidance!

Answer (score 0):

Because you want to know if your steps for simplifying the diagram are correct:
There is one small - but important - error: If you want to place the block "gain of two" at the signal output you must multiply it with "s" (because now it is integrated) - that`s all. Thus, your second diagram would be correct if you remove  the most right line which acts as a short for the block "2s".

As a result, we have **H(s)=N(s)/D(s)**

with **N(s)=10/s(s+1)** and **D(s)=[1+LG]** with loop gain **LG=N(s)*2s**

Introducing all the corresponding expressions into H(s) results in the given formula.